# radEditor inside radGrid is not functioning correctly

Tags: asp.net

I am adding a radEditor to a radGrid which is on pop up window for an ASP.Net application. However when I add the control and render the page the radEditor is unresponsive and does not allow me to add text or use any of the controls on the toolbar. 
  When I debug in the browser there is an error message "Uncaught Type Error: object is not a function". Is there any known issues of having the radEditor inside a radGrid?

```
<div>
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel>  
   <telerik:RadGrid>  
      <mastertableview>  
         <EditFormSettings>
            <FormTemplate>
               <div>
                  <telerik:RadEditor ID="radID" runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("stuff") %>'></telerik:RadEditor>
               </div>
 `         </FormTemplate>
         </EditFormSettings>
      </mastertableview>
     </telerik:RadGrid>  
  </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</div>enter code here
```